# Building a LAN emulator for gaming purposes

Tags: networking, lan, port-forwarding, gaming, upnp

I built a simple utility for Warcraft III that allows users to join remotely hosted games just as if they were accessible in their LAN. Its idea is pretty straightforward:

1. Players A and B want to play. They set up port forwarding on their routers, launch my utility and exchange their external IP addresses.
2. Players then enter each others' IP addresses in my utility and one of the players creates a Warcraft III game.
3. My utility uses the Warcraft III packet format to query its local machine for any hosted Warcraft III games. If it receives a response (with game information), it simply forwards it to every IP on the list.
4. Due to port forwarding, the packet (datagram, to be more specific) reaches the other Warcraft III instance and so the other user is now able to see his friend's game, as well as join it.

It works very well. However, it still requires users to set port forwarding and here's my question - what would be the best approach to avoid it?

I've been thinking about UPnP / NAT-PMP but that's mostly useful when it is my application that is listening. In this case, I only notify Warcraft III on the other end that there's a game on my machine. But can I create a port mapping for another application?

I'm surely missing something out, so I'd be glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I know about at least few programs that work exactly like yours. There's also [Garena](http://intl.garena.com/) that should do the trick.

Comment: The thing is - I'd like to implement it myself and I'm just looking for suggestions on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reliable standard way to tell a remote system on a different NATted network to open a port for an application on a local system.

You have three basic methods to avoid user setup of port forwarding with most applications:

A. Tell user they are SOL unless they directly connect their computer or device to an Internet whose ISP does not block incoming traffic. This is a bad idea.

B. Telling the router to open a port programmatically using something like uPNP.  This assumes their router supports it.

C. Having a well-known system outside of any NATted network to which clients may make outgoing connections.  This system may also need to forward traffic on behalf of clients.

The proper term for "LAN emulator" is *virtual private network.*  Hamachi and OpenVPN are two software suites that set up a VPN.  I'm betting Garena as mentioned by @gronostaj operates similarly with a gamer-friendly interface.

A VPN will fall into category C - you'll need a VPN server that's accessible outside of anyone's NAT for it to work.  A VPN would work well - the virtual network would function just like a LAN and systems that are on the VPN can receive incoming connections from any other system on the VPN.

I'm pretty sure you don't want to bear the expense and responsibility of operating a centrally accessible VPN - not to mention that restricting it to Warcraft-only usage will be difficult and a lot more responsibility.

I haven't used Hamachi very much so I'm not sure if you can leverage it to achieve what you want.

The best you can probably do is to support uPnP and include port forwarding instructions for common routers with your software.

Comment: AFAIR, Garena uses external servers to set up connections between players. It's the Garena client that initiates the connection to bypass NAT. Still, it's one of the players who hosts the game, but all traffic is proxied through Garena servers.